# Angularjs select with ng-options calling a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

here is my html

```
 <select ng-model="selectedMarker" ng-options="shape.text for shape in Selects('shapes')">
            </select>
```

and the code

```
 angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])
        .factory('Projects', function ($http) {
            return {
                options: function (type) {
            var selects = [{
                type: "shapes",
                list: [{
                    text: "Circle",
                    value: "S"
                }, {
                    text: "Polygon",
                    value: "P"
                }]
            }];
            var _filter = selects.filter(function (item) {
                if (item.type === type) {
                    return item.list;
                }
            });
            return _filter;
        },
     })
        .controller('TodoCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $ionicModal, Projects, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
            $scope.map = null;
            $scope.Selects = function (type) {
                var x= Projects.options(type);
                return x;
            }
    });
```

This results in rendering an empty select. i replaced $scope.Selects as an array instead of calling a function, but then the select gets populated. Why is that ng-options does not work with a function? Is there anything wrong with my select tag?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is wrong (not to mention overly complicated).

The `options` function returns the original `selects` array and not the `shapes` array.
It is not clear what exactly are you trying to achive, but if you change `var xx = _filter[0];` to `var xx = _filter[0][type];` it should work.

<sub>I strongly suggest you take a closer look at what the functions you are using do (e.g. `filter`), because there might be surprises coming your way...</sub>

Comment: ah sorry, my options definition was wrong. i did it that way because i will be having a lot of selects, so iwanted to keep it all inside an array and query it with a parameter, makes it look a bit more clean.